# Android UI component design

Tags: android

I found this application on YouTube and playstore and was wondering what kind of UI component these are (the marked one on the the first image and the things in circle in the second image) It's be great if you could point me in a direction to build stuff like these in android studio. Thanks in advance.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZxGS.jpg)

Comment: It most likely a completely custom view.  Neither would be that difficult to build with Canvas and draw commands.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about android canvas. Will look into it, thank you. Do you know any libraries or something like that for that?